# Dynamically binding data contained within an object to labels in a windows form

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following data and objects in my program.

A DynamicObjectContainer that contains the following objects.

1. `MeasurementParameters : DataContainer` (DataContainer is the base class)

This `MeasurementParameters` object has many public properties, whose names I know *only* during runtime. I have also set up internal wiring in the `DataContainer` base class such that, I can access the values of the properties contained in the `MeasurementParameters` class using an easy to use interface.

Ex : Say I have a property in `MeasurementParameters` named as "pumpspeed" (type string). I can access the value of that property using this function.

```
MeasurementParameters.GetStringValue("pumpspeed");
```

I have achieved this by creating lists of delegates internally in the `DataContainer` object using reflection during construction of the object. (This is a one time thing.)

So far so good.

Now I am stuck at the point where I want to display these values within `MeasurementParameters` in a windows form.

Since I only know the property names at runtime, I have to provide the user with some method to map the property names (defined only by him in a script file) to the fixed labels within the form. So the user saves the mapping data to the table in the following format.

```
Entry : "pumpspeed" "label22"
```

I want a fast and efficient method to fetch this mapping from the database, fetch required data from the `MeasuremetParameters` object and display it in the windows form.

NOTE : If this is a one time operation, I have many solutions. The problem is two fold.

1. There are a huge number of properties in the `MeasurementParameters` (at around 200)
2. The `MeasurementParameters` object contains functions that update it's properties continuously. SO My windows form has to call those functions to update the `MeasurementParameters` object data, fetch the data and display it in the correct labels.

ALSO, this should happen in cycles of around 2 -3 times a second. (ideally)

Can anyone help me in architecting a solution for this?? A general object structure and relationship advice will also be helpful to me.

I can post the code I am using if required.

Comment: I'm not seeing a huge problem here. It looks like the mapping is a one off so Building up a Dictionary Ker PropertyName and Control

Comment: I have actually tried that. I have built a dictionary that maps labelname to a corresponding value. But on my fairly powerful system, for around 100 properties, it takes around 180 milliseconds for searching through the dictionary and updating the labels. I am looking for something that can be done quickly. It is taking so much time because of all the searcing associated with a dictionary, that too search of strings.

Comment: Event based might cut into that, a bit messier but doable would be an integer propertyID instead of using property name. SortedDictionary might be a quick boost as well.

Comment: Oh and mu answer doesn't used label name it uses the label itself, looking up the control by name to set it will cost you as well. You can take one hit for that if you do property name and control in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing a huge problem here

So you have Table ObjectID, PropertyName, ControlName

On opening the form / selecting the object, query them out
Build a `Dictionary` Keyed by PropertyName with a Value of the Label (looked up by the name of teh control from the query `MyForm.Controls.FindByName(Somename).` Add an `OnPropertyChangedEvent` to your class that throws up the name of the Property in event args then add a handler on the form

```
Mappings[e.PropertyName].Text = Object[e.PropertyName].GetStringValue;
```

Might have to twidlle with it to deal with say display controls that aren't Labels, or Panels on the Form, but it should just batter away.